# Filter by numeric column start with a given number

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to filter my rows based on a numeric column. Problem is that the input is a pattern - for e.g. - a number starting with 2045 or something. I could do this:

```
select *
from my_table
where num_column like '2045%';
```

It works but that doesn't let me use index on the column. The implicit `to_char` on num_column reduces the performance.

Is there a more suitable way in which I could query the same and still use indexes?

This assumes the number always *start* with the given input (not in between or end) and the value in the column is of variable number of digits.

Comment: How many digits at most?

Comment: it can have up to 17 digits.

Comment: If number always start with given input what about using `CONCAT(your_input, num_column)`

Comment: @juergend - What about 20451, 20452 etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number is in a particular range, then you could do something like:

```
where num_column >= 2045000 and num_column < 2046000
```

I am guessing that is not the case . . . although you could extend this:

```
where (num_column >= 2045 and num_column < 2046) or
      (num_column >= 20450 and num_column < 20460) or
      (num_column >= 204500 and num_column < 204600) or
      . . .
```

I'm not sure if Oracle would really use an index for a complicated `or`.

There is another solution.  Create an index on an expression and use the expression:

```
create index idx_mytable_numcolumn_str on my_table(to_char(num_column));
```

Then you can do:

```
where to_char(num_column) like '2045%'
```

Comment: Perfect. The second solution looks great. In this case, I wouldn't even have to change my SQL.

Comment: @GurV Note that adding indexes is not always the right approach. You need to see it doesn't effect other places.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more suitable way in which I could query the same and still use indexes?

Create a function-based index on your column.

```
CREATE INDEX my_table__num_column__to_char__idx ON my_table ( TO_CHAR( num_column ) );
```